# Retrieving the minimum and maximum Datetime value from a signle Date column in laravel eloquent query

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I am working on retrieving records in group with date-time from my table called 'sales'

[image: Sample Database record am to retrieve form]

The expected output i wanted was to be in such rows

[image: Output from database Query]

The **starting date** from the output is expected to give the first day record of the production group list i.e 2022-06-08, the ending day is for the last day ie 2022-0-22.

I have tried several queries in trying to get on to that but it all returns error.

here are some codes that i used

I saw this info from
https://docs.trifacta.com/display/SS/MAXDATE+Function

```
 $this->sales = DB::table('sales')
      ->select(
            \DB::raw('maxdate("s_date") as firstDay','mindate("sales.s_date") as lastDay', 'sum("qty") as totalAmount','sum("leaking") as totalExpenses'), 'sales.productions_pr_id'
        )
        ->groupBy('productions_pr_id')
        ->get();
```

I have also used Max(date) format and all i get is erros.

```
  $this->sales = DB::table('sales')
          ->select(
                \DB::raw('max("s_date") as firstDay','min("sales.s_date") as lastDay', 'sum("qty") as totalAmount','sum("leaking") as totalExpenses'), 'sales.productions_pr_id'
            )
            ->groupBy('productions_pr_id')
            ->get();
```

I have gone through quite some number of solution but couldn't find similar to my problem. I am only interested in query that will give me the first date of example production_pr_id =1

Comment: What error do you get? Before that, get rid of the quotes embracing the column names inside the functions `min, max, sum`. That is to say it should be `\DB::raw('max(s_date) as firstDay','mi...`

Comment: `\DB::raw('max(s_date) as firstDay` gives me an output of **s_date** as a string.  if i use  `\DB::raw('max(sales.s_date) as firstDay`  referering to sales table and s_date column. it gives out **sales.s_date** as the output

Comment: Using `maxdate ` gives the error **Syntax error or access violation: 1305 FUNCTION humsad.maxdate does not exist**  @user3532758

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem with the following procedure

1. Removing the "" in  `\DB::raw('max("s_date")` ie changing it to  `\DB::raw('max(s_date)`

my final code looks like

```
$this->sales = DB::table('sales')
        ->select(
            \DB::raw('min(sales.s_date) as firstDay'),\DB::raw('max(sales.s_date) as lastDay'), \DB::raw('sum((qty*100)-(leaking)) as totalAmount'),\DB::raw('sum(leaking) as totalExpenses'), 'sales.productions_pr_id'
        )
        ->groupBy('sales.productions_pr_id')
        ->get();
```